# Testing when a ValidationError is raised

Tags: django, python-2.7, testing, validationerror

I am new to programming and Django in general.  I am trying to test one of my functions to make sure that a validation error is raised.  The test confirms that the error is raised but also says the test Failed.  How is this possible?

```
**models.py**
def check_user_words(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for field in instance._meta.get_fields():
        #field_name = getattr(instance, field.attname)
        if (isinstance(field, models.CharField) and
            contains_bad_words(getattr(instance, field.attname))):
            raise ValidationError("We don't use words like '{}' around here!".format(getattr(instance, field.attname)))

#tests.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import datetime
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Question, Choice, contains_bad_words, check_user_words
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def create_question(question_text, days):
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)


class ContainsBadWordsTests(TestCase):
    def test_check_user_words(self):
    question = create_question(question_text="What a minute bucko", days=1)
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        check_user_words(question)
        question.full_clean()

#after running python manage.py test polls
......
raise ValidationError("We don't use words like '{}' around here!".format(getattr(instance, field.attname)))
ValidationError: [u"We don't use words like 'What a minute bucko' around here!"]
```

## models.py How I import

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals .... (and others)

filepath = "polls/static/polls/blacklist.yaml"
config = yaml_loader(filepath)
blacklist = [word.lower() for word in config['blacklist']]

def contains_bad_words(user_input_txt):
""" remove punctuation from text
    and make it case-insensitive"""
    user_typ = user_input_txt.encode()
    translate_table = maketrans(string.punctuation, 32 * " ")
    words = user_typ.translate(translate_table).lower().split()
    for bad_word in blacklist:
        for word in words:
            if word == bad_word:
                return True
    return False

@receiver(pre_save)
def check_user_words(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for field in instance._meta.get_fields():
        if (isinstance(field, models.CharField) and
            contains_bad_words(getattr(instance, field.attname))):
        raise ValidationError("We don't use words like '{}' around here!".format(getattr(instance, field.attname)))
```

Comment: Whats the actual test failure reason? You could probably check if you are referring to the same `ValidationError` type

Comment: Other than what i've shown, this is all is shows:

Comment: Ran 11 tests in 0.061s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Comment: So the test is raising the exception as it should, i can't figure out why the test would fail.

Comment: Please show us how you are importing `ValidationError` in your tests.

Comment: Hi @solarissmoke, I added the pieces of the test.py file that shows how i import Validationerror.  Does this help?  Please let me know if I've provided enough info to diagnose.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: @stud333 Can you also show how you import it in models.py?

Comment: @bdbd  I added how I import and left out other lines I didn't think was necessary to see b/c stackoverflow was complaining i have more code than comments.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see more of your code (specifically `create_question()` and how `check_user_words` is connected to a signal) to be sure, but I think the issue is that you are using a `post_save` signal handler to execute `check_user_words()`.

If this is the case, then the reason your test is failing is that `create_question()` will cause the `post_save` signal to fire, and `check_user_words()` will be executed immediately - i.e., *before* the `with self.assertRaises` context, and hence your test fails.

If this is the case, then try this:

```
def test_check_user_words(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        create_question(question_text="What a minute bucko", days=1)
```

This test should now pass, because the validation error will be thrown as soon as you try to create the question.

Note however that doing this in a signal will result in an uncaught exception when something tries to save an object. Depending on what your use case is, you might be better off doing this in the `clean()` method of the model itself ([see docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)), because this will cause appropriate errors to be reported on model forms etc:

```
def clean(self):
    for field in instance._meta.get_fields():    
        if (isinstance(field, models.CharField) and contains_bad_words(getattr(instance, field.attname))):
            raise ValidationError("We don't use words like '{}' around here!".format(getattr(instance, field.attname)))
```

(and then drop your signal handler). Then you can test this with:

```
q = create_question(question_text="What a minute bucko", days=1)
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    q.clean()
```

Comment: Your intuition is correct!  Thank you for that!  Only thing is its a pre_save, not post_save.  I've added more of my models.py code above.  If my intention is a pre-save and what I'm really testing is if the check_user_words() function works(throws exception),  would it still be correct to use your suggestion above?

Comment: Yeah, the same applies with `pre_save()`. That code will get executed as soon as you try to create the question, so the code I have posted above will still work to verify that the validation occurs. That said, I have edited the answer to suggest an alternative approach that doesn't use signals.

Comment: Thank you so much!! If I want to use pre_save signal to check and validate some condition before saving, what would the appropriate way to do this?  After definining my two classes in models.py, I have the following code:

Comment: pre_save.connect(check_user_words, sender=Question)

Comment: pre_save.connect(check_user_words, sender=Choice)

Comment: You can do that, but then you need to catch the `ValidationError` yourself and decide what to do with it, in all the places that create/save these objects. Otherwise it will just propagate up.